# How do I determine what kind of replacement shifters I need?

Tags: shifter

I need shifters for a 16 speed bicycle. When shifters are advertised as 2x8 is this referring to a bicycle with 2 sprockets in the front and 8 in the back?

Comment: They're called chainrings in the front and yes.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that 2x8 refers to 8 speed cassette or freewheel and a crank with 2 speeds. The one that can be confusing is 18speed which can be an older 3x6 or a more modern 2x9. The other concerns is mountain or road drivetrain and Shimano, Sram or Campagnolo  compatible. You can search this site for compatibility questions that may match your specific circumstances.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it gets more complex all the time, with different shifters and chains and sprockets required based on how many sprockets are in the rear cluster, among other things.